# Putting an Alias in a Partial Select Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it possible to use an alias in a partial select? Because I use underscore as the naming convention for the variables in the front-end and camelCasing in the back-end.

Here's my doctrine query:

```
return $this->postingRepo->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p.postingId','p.datetimePosted')
        ->innerJoin('p.user','u')
        ->addSelect('partial u.{userId as user_id,firstName as first_name,lastName as last_name}') // ----> generates an error message
        ->orderBy('p.datetimePosted','DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

I've searched plenty of times already but still can't find an answer. Maybe someone knows how or wants to inform me that it's not possible.

Comment: I tried many things already like putting the properties in single quotes with and without the 'as', change the sequence and many more. I guess this isn't possible since no one's replying.

Comment: What does your user entity look like and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just wondering - did you try `partial u.{userId} as user_id`?

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer to this? I'm trying to do something like that and can't find how. I know this question is quite old maybe is a new way of doing it?